# How do I get Launchy to open Chromium?

Tags: chromium, ruby, launchy

I'm developing in rails on my computer.  I'm just going along with what tutorials say, and I simply cannot find anything about how to use launchy during development on the Internet .. period.  There are two problems:

- I'd like `launchy` to open Chromium (it opens Firefox).  Chromium is set as my default browser.
- I save files constantly, and `launchy` will run each time, which is terrible.  Is there any way to only get it to run when you actually want?  This also applies to `guard`, but it's not nearly as annoying with `guard`.

Comment: This should be moved to StackOverflow, you'll have better luck there.

Comment: @william potentially, yes. It is on-topic for here though.

Answer (score 2):

Lets address this piece by piece.

- Looks like a "bug" of sorts in launchy itself. - https://github.com/copiousfreetime/launchy/issues/40
- Are you running your tests via `guard`, and having that trigger launchy? If so, then please post your guardfile, it's possible to do some tricks with it.